# Prove that $O(3^{2n}) \subseteq O(2^{3n})$

Tags: computational-complexity

I need to prove that $O(3^{2n}) \subseteq O(2^{3n})$. So far I have made this solution:

I)Lets assume that this is true, and that there $ \exists \space c \in \mathbb{R}^+ $ such as $$3^{2n} \leq 2^{3n} * c$$

II) therefore this fraction must be greater or equal as $1$

$$\frac{c*2^{3n}}{3^{2n}} \geq 1$$

III) lets look on $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{c*2^{3n}}{3^{2n}}=(\frac{8}{9})^n=0$$ since the limit is equal to $0$ there occurs an conflict that shows us that II) can not ever be greater or equal as $1$. Is my solution correct? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is false.

Comment: The statement in your question's title is the other way round to the statement in the body.

Comment: Edited the title, thanks

Comment: Now the title and the body are different (small-o vs big-O) and both wrong.

Comment: Edited again, it should be fine now.

Answer (score 1):

This is false.

Suppose it holds: then, since obviously $3^{2n} \in O(3^{2n}) \subseteq O(2^{3n}) \implies 3^{2n} \in O(2^{3n})$, $\lim_{n \to \infty}\, \sup |\frac{9}{8}|^n < \infty$, which obviously does not hold.

Answer (score 1):

More generally,
when is
$a^{bn} \subseteq c^{dn}$?

$a^{bn}
=(e^{\ln(a)})^{bn}
=e^{\ln(a)b n}
=(e^n)^{\ln(a)b }
=(e^n)^{\ln(a^b) }
$.

Therefore
$a^{bn} \subseteq c^{dn}
\iff \ln(a^b) \le \ln(c^d)
\iff a^b \le c^d
$.

Putting 
$a=3, b=2, c=2, d=3$,
this is true
iff
$3^2 \le 2^3$,
which is false.

For the case
$c=b, d=a$,
i.e.,
when is
$a^{bn} \subseteq b^{an}
$,
this is the old problem
of when
$a^b \le b^a$,
or
$a^{1/a} \le b^{1/b}$.

It is well known that
this is true when
$e \le b \lt a$.

The case
$a < e < b$
is trickier.
I have a result that shows
this is decided if
$ab > e^2$
but I can't find it right now.
I'll add to this if
I find it.